# NSScreen leaking under GarbageCollection, Is this a bug

Tags: macos, garbage-collection, core-graphics

I've been trying to debug memory leaks in an objective-c program for the last couple of days and was playing around with some very basic sample code to test some ideas and came across something that seems to be a bug to me but wanted to get some opinions from those with more knowledge when it comes to developing in the Mac world.

I have the following bit of code:

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

NSRect desktopRect = NSZeroRect;

NSArray* screens = [[NSScreen screens] autorelease];
int x = 0;
for (x = 0; x < [screens count]; x++)
{
    NSScreen *screen = [screens objectAtIndex:x];
}   

[pool drain];
```

This code lives inside a method that I am calling from a while loop that continues until I kill the process. (Remember this is just a simple test.)

When I run this loop and watch allocations in Instruments things work perfectly fine when I am not implementing Garbage Collection. My overall number of allocations stays constant and everything with the NSScreens are getting cleaned up and released.

As soon as I enable Garbage Collection, the call to [NSScreen screens] starts leaking core graphics objects like mad by never releasing them.

I have seen in other forums where people a few years back talked about Core Graphics being very leaky under Garbage Collection. I'm wondering if that is the case here as well.

Any thoughts from the community?

Comment: Why are you autoreleasing `[NSScreen screens]`? You don't own it.

Comment: Peter, the problem I was having is that the background core graphics objects created by the call were never being released. I will admit that autorelease didn't do anything in the above example, it was a hope on my part that it would allow the underlying CG objects to be released.

Comment: That doesn't matter. You should never release what you don't own. Even if it would have “helped”, it would still have been wrong, and would have set you up for a crash when Apple fixes the bug. Moreover, you're running under GC, so retain, release, and autorelease messages don't go through anyway—the runtime ignores them entirely. http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/GarbageCollection/

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'm going to go out on a limb here and say that yes it is a bug on Apples part though I did find a solution using some Toll-Free-Bridging magic. I modified the code to be:

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

NSRect desktopRect = NSZeroRect;

CFArrayRef screens = CFMakeCollectable((CFArrayRef)[NSScreen screens]);
int x = 0;
for (x = 0; x < [screens count]; x++)
{
    NSScreen *screen = (NSScreen*)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(screens,x);
}   

[pool drain];
```

By calling CFMakeCollectable on the toll-free-bridged array, it allowed the background core graphics objects to be properly cleaned up when using garbage collection.

This definitely makes me think that Apple needs to do some more work with Garbage Collection and Cocoa objects that wrap Core Graphics.

Comment: Alternatively, use `NSMakeCollectable`, then treat it as an NSArray. I don't know whether this is safe for you to do if Apple fixes the bug, though. It may be better to just let it leak for now (and cache the array to limit the damage) and report the bug in RadarWeb. https://bugreport.apple.com/